# angular js page transition with ng-enter ng-leave

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I am new to angular JS and trying to do some page animations (enter and leave). I am working on a project set up by a different person and can not get the generic ng-enter and ng-leave animations to trigger. What I read is I can simply add css3 transiition to those classes and it would work out of the box by no such luck. In the main app.js file we have ng-animate on like so

```
  return ng.module('app', [
    'app.constants',
      'app.controllers',
      'app.directives',
      'app.filters',
      'app.services',
      'ngRoute',
      'ngAnimate',
      'ngSanitize'
  ]).run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.clearAnimation = false;
  });
});
```

and the css

```
@keyframes rotateFall {
    0%    { transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
    20%   { transform: rotateZ(10deg); animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    40%   { transform: rotateZ(17deg); }
    60%   { transform: rotateZ(16deg); }
    100%  { transform: translateY(100%) rotateZ(17deg); }
  }

  /* slide in from the bottom */
  @keyframes slideOutLeft {
    to    { transform: translateX(-100%); }
  }

  /* rotate out newspaper */
  @keyframes rotateOutNewspaper {
    to    { transform: translateZ(-3000px) rotateZ(360deg); opacity: 0; }
  }

  /* entering animations --------------------------------------- */
  /* scale up */
  @keyframes scaleUp {
    from  { opacity: 0.3; -webkit-transform: scale(0.8); }
  }

  /* slide in from the right */
  @keyframes slideInRight {
    from  { transform:translateX(100%); }
    to    { transform: translateX(0); }
  }

  /* slide in from the bottom */
  @keyframes slideInUp {
    from  { transform:translateY(100%); }
    to    { transform: translateY(0); }
  }

  .ng-enter       { animation: scaleUp 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 8888; }
  .ng-leave       { animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 9999; }
```

and how I navigate in a page

```
<li class="hex lrg residential market hide" ng-click="navigate('/tours/residential')"><p>Residential</p></li>
```

The everything works (pages and site) just no transitions. Did I miss something?